# mediawiki-i want to check that the user if logged in or not for chage in created page

Tags: php, mediawiki

in my local i created many page using mediawiki template and any one can see that page, but i want to put one link for edit page. and i want to do like this "if user is already login then edit the page if not login then when click on that link then page redirect to login page, and after login user edit the page"...

(it's possible to take session value in template for check if condition because my plan to use if condition,... )

if any other solution then also give me

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an [extension that provides a parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser_functions), that checks if a user is logged in or not (there is no built in way to check this). Writing such an extension is quite straight forward (see below), but be aware that this makes it impossible to cache the page where the parser function is used, making the page load *much* slower. If you need to do this on a regular content page, a front end (javascript) solution that modifies the page content after loading it, would most likely be a better option. Anyway, here's a possible solution:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'efLoggedinParserFunction_Setup';

function efLoggedinParserFunction_Setup( &$parser ) {
    $parser->setFunctionHook( 'loggedin', 'efLoggedinParserFunction_Render' );
    return true;
}

function efLoggedinParserFunction_Magic( &$magicWords, $langCode ) {
    $magicWords['loggedin'] = array( 0, 'loggedin' );
    return true;
}

function efLoggedinParserFunction_Render( $parser) {
    $res = $parser->getUser()->isLoggedIn(); 
return array( $res, 'noparse' => false);
}
```

This should give you a parser function `{{#loggedin}}` that returns `true` or `false`, so that you can write eg. `{{#ifeq:{{#loggedin}}|true| Welcome, logged in user! }}`

Please note that I didn't test this code at all.